# How to make HAProxy rotate more faster?

Tags: http, proxy, haproxy

I have set up rotating proxies with HAProxy successfully.

Following is part of haproxy.cfg;

```
frontend RotatingProxies1000
        bind 0.0.0.0:1000
        default_backend Proxies1000
        option http_proxy
        option httpclose
        option http-use-proxy-header

backend Proxies1000
        server fp0 1.1.1.1:8800
        server fp1 2.2.2.2:8800
        server fp2 3.3.3.3:8800
        server fp3 4.4.4.4:8800
        ...
        balance roundrobin
```

But i notice the rotation speed is very slow.

I made test in the Firefox, I looked up the client ip address on http://whatismyipaddress.com/.

First it's 1.1.1.1. I refreshed the page, still 1.1.1.1, refreshed again, still 1.1.1.1.
One minute later i refreshed again it became 2.2.2.2.

How to make HAProxy rotate more faster?

According to Baptiste and Willy's suggestions. I tried to add "mode http" and remove "option http_proxy".
The current config, but it's still slow to rotate IPs:

```
global
        log 127.0.0.1   local0 notice
        maxconn 4096
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        retries 3
        maxconn 2000
        contimeout      5000
        clitimeout      50000
        srvtimeout      50000

frontend RotatingProxies1000
        bind 0.0.0.0:1000
        default_backend Proxies1000
        #option http_proxy
        mode http
        option httpclose
        option http-use-proxy-header

backend Proxies1000
        server fp0 1.1.1.1:8800
        server fp1 2.2.2.2:8800
        server fp2 3.3.3.3:8800
        server fp3 4.4.4.4:8800
        ...
        balance roundrobin
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration misses timeouts and http mode.

My assumption is that your browser does not close the connection with HAProxy because of you configuration, so HAProxy can't balance you to an other server until a new connexion is established.

Comment: I did't paste the defaults section, timeouts are there. Won't "httpclose" force the client to disconnect?

Comment: Baptiste told you that you also miss "mode http". Normally you should have warnings with this configuraion. Also you should remove "option http_proxy", it's only used in backends to disable load balancing and pick the server's address from the request, which is not what you're trying here.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to add "mode http" and comment out "option http_proxy", but it's still slow to rotate IPs.